# I'm unable to install Moq nuget package for ASP.NET5 (core CLR) Unable to locate Dependency moq.netcore >= 4.4.0-beta8

Tags: moq, coreclr, asp.net5

I'm playing with new Core CLR code and trying to implement some test project. I found that Moq at the current moment not support Core CLR and there is package from MS guys called `moq.netcore`. But when I'm adding this in my list of dependacies like `moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8"` I get this error:

`Unable to locate Dependency moq.netcore >= 4.4.0-beta8`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add special source to your nuget package manager to be able to locate dev version of packages by MS team.

URL of sources where you could find this packet is `https://www.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json`

if you prefer command line I think this command should work:

```
nuget sources add -name FeedName -Source https://www.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json
```

or click to nugget settings in Visual Studio and add it manually (you could check [there for example](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/02/22/moq-on-net-core/))